# Oracle table -Find the job in scheduler

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle which is filled with data from an excel sheet on daily basis. I heard from a colleague that some job in the oracle scheduler has been running dail to update the table. Is there any way to find the exact job?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to get a list of all scheduled jobs in Oracle using the below query. After that, you would have to check the jobs individually to figure out which job is updating your table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS;
```